# html purifier library usage concept

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string, xss, htmlpurifier

Hi
I am at prototype stage with my site. I read the html purifier main page and questions about this library in this site but I am still not clear with the issue on my mind. Can you guide me please?
Thanks, BR
**My Understanding:**
From the docs I have read, I understood that the best I can do is:

1. to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` while *inputting untrusted data
   into my mysql database*
2. to use html purifier library *while outputting data from mysql
   database to sscreen as html*

**My Questions**
**Q1)** Does my understanding makes sense?
**Q2)** Do I still another sanitization method while inputting data into mysql or  outputting from mysql to screen? I think these 2 methods are pretty enough for an amateur but can you please share your idea.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: You should *not* be using `*_real_escape_string` to escape text! You should be parametrizing your queries instead.